# Clone select element with selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsbin.com/jejujizi/1/edit

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cs").on('click', function() {
    $(".newclones").append("<div class='container'>").append($(".toclone .clone").clone()).append("<button class='rem'>Delete</button>");

    $(".rem").on('click', function() {
      $(this).prev().remove();
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
});
```

Cloning a select element isn't the problem, cloning the select element with a changed value is the problem.  (as you can see in my fiddle)

Why is it not cloning the changed value, and how can this be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [`clone()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/clone):

> For performance reasons, the dynamic state of certain form elements (e.g., user data typed into `textarea` and user selections made to a `select`) is not copied to the cloned elements.

Instead, you simply need to copy the value yourself after you've cloned the element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cs").on('click', function() {
    var toClone = $('.toclone .clone');
    var toCloneClone = toClone.clone().val(toClone.val());

    $(".newclones").append("<div class='container'>").append(toCloneClone).append("<button class='rem'>Delete</button>");

    $(".rem").on('click', function() {
      $(this).prev().remove();
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/qocuyuhi/1/